# Retaining same WSS 3.0 URL on new SharePoint 2010 server

Tags: deployment

SharePoint Admin Newbie here so my apologies if this has been asked before, etc....

Is it possible to reuse our existing WSS 3.0 URL (e.g. http://sharept.domain.com on server abc) on our new SharePoint 2010 server (e.g. http://sharept.domain.com on server xyz)?

If yes, is it possible to keep our WSS 3.0 server available in case we need to access it?

Rather than come up with a new name for our users for the SharePoint 2010 server, we'd like to allow them to continue using the same.

Is this an unusual idea?  I haven't stumbled on anything relating to the same sort of scenario.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to keep the same name in the new environment. You need only to redirect your DNS entry to the new servers. As for the old servers, you can rename the url to -OLD or set up host file entries on the servers and then you can get to them from within the servers only for reference or to retrieve information. My recommendation is to rename the URLs and then to create a DNS entry for those, that gives you much more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds good but how do I get the URL to go to appropriate Web App on the new server if the Web App is already created?

Comment: You can create an alternate access mapping for the new URL in the new location. The rest is setting up DNS.